# Question regarding supplying parseInt to map

Tags: javascript, parseint

Why is it that, when I use parseInt explicitly with the first argument, everything works as I expect, but with I straight up supply the parseInt function to map, it becomes like you can see in the picture?

I've read up a little bit on the second radix-argument of parseInt, and I suppose it has something to do with that. But I still don't understand what JS internally supplies to the parseInt function as the second argument when I don't explicitly do it myself. Does anyone know?

[image: parseInt]

Comment: MDN addresses this exact scenario [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Tricky_use_case)

Answer (score 0):

Because `.map` calls function with two parameters, the second being an index of an element, so your `parseInt` call in the second case gets strange radix.

Example:

```
> function f(x, y) {
... console.log(x, y);
... }
undefined
> [1, 2, 3, 4].map(x => x.toString()).map(f)
1 0
2 1
3 2
4 3
```

When you call `.map(parseInt)`, then `parseInt` gets both. When you call `.map(x => parseInt(x))` the second gets ignored, and `parseInt` is called with one parameter only and default radix.

(Actually, there's the third argument as well; read `Array.map` documentation.)

Comment: Ahh, I see. Thank you so much!

Comment: Three, not two: `let new_array = arr.map(function callback( currentValue[, index[, array]]) {/* return element for new_array */ }[, thisArg])`

Answer (score 0):

It's because all of the array methods pass 3 arguments to your callbacks, the first argument is the array element at each index, the second argument is the index, and the last one is the array itself. When you pass a reference to a callback directly like in your second example, Javascript implicitly passes all 3 arguments into your callback, so the indices being passed in your `parseInt` are used as the radix, and when `parseInt` is given an invalid radix, it just returns `NaN`. While in your first example, you explicitly pass only the array elements yourself, and you are leaving out the radix argument for `parseInt`, so base 10 is assumed

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! Now I know more clearly what's going on when you use a function like that in map for example. Yay!

Comment: I realize now with the great answers in this thread, that I can do ["1","2","3"].map(Number) instead and it will work as I originally expected, because Number only has one parameter!